# Multiple dropdown not working using Jquery and Ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to make multiple dropdown menu using bootstrap, JQuery and AJAX. I want to select multiple countries from the dropdown menu and enter the selected values to my database in CSV Form. The code below was working fine for 1 dropdown menu. But I wanted to replicate it and want a total of 3 dropdown menus. It was working for 2 menus, but it is not working for 3 menus. Clicking on Submit Button does nothing, that means the form is not being submitted and hence nothing is being inserted in my db.
[UPDATE: Above problem was solved in a way such that selected values of third dropdown is being inserted. But not in the way that I want.]
 Below is my index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Tutorial</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
   <h2 align="center">Bootstrap Multi Select Dropdown with Checkboxes using Jquery in PHP</h2>
   <br /><br />
   <form method="post" id="framework_form">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Select country</label><br>
     <select id="markappcountry" name="markappcountry[]" multiple class="form-control" >
      <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
        <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
        <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
     </select>
    </div>

   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Select second country</label><br/>
     <select id="country" name="markcountry[]" multiple class="form-control" >
      <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
        <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
        <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
        <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
     </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Select third country</label><br/>
     <select id="thirdcountry" name="thirdcountry[]" multiple class="form-control" >
      <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
        <option value="American">American Samoa</option>
        <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
        <option value="Wake Island">Wake Island</option>
        <option value="Wallis &amp; Futana Is">Wallis &amp; Futana Is</option>
        <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
        <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
        <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
     </select>
    </div>


   <div class="form-group">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
   </form>
   <br />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#markappcountry').multiselect({
  nonSelectedText: 'Select Country',
  enableFiltering: true,
  enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
  buttonWidth:'400px'
 });

 $('#country').multiselect({
  nonSelectedText: 'Select another Country',
  enableFiltering: true,
  enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
  buttonWidth:'400px'
 });    

 $('#thirdcountry').multiselect({
  nonSelectedText: 'Select third Country',
  enableFiltering: true,
  enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
  buttonWidth:'400px'
 });

 $('#framework_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:form_data,
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#markappcountry option:selected').each(function(){
     $(this).prop('selected', false);
    });
    $('#markappcountry').multiselect('refresh');
    alert(data);
   }
  });
 });


});

</script>
```

Below is my Insert.php. Through this, I am trying to first establish connection and then insert the selected values from dropdown menus into my db.

```
   <?php 
//insert.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "abcdef", "testing");

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $markappcountry =   !empty($_POST['markappcountry']) ? $_POST['markappcountry'] : "";

    if(isset($_POST["markappcountry"])){
        $framework = '';
        foreach($_POST["markappcountry"] as $row){
            $framework .= $row . ', ';
        }
        $framework = substr($framework, 0, -2);
        $query = "INSERT INTO like_table(framework) VALUES('".$framework."')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $query);
     }

    $countryy = !empty($_POST['markcountry']) ? $_POST['markcountry'] : "";

    if(isset($_POST["markcountry"])){
        $countryy = '';
        foreach($_POST["markcountry"] as $row) {
            $countryy .= $row . ', ';
        }
        $countryy = substr($countryy, 0, -2);
        $query = "INSERT INTO like_table(country) VALUES('".$countryy."')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    }

    $thirdcountryy =     !empty($_POST['thirdcountry']) ? $_POST['thirdcountry'] : "";

    if(isset($_POST["thirdcountry"])){
        $thirdcountryy = '';
        foreach($_POST["thirdcountry"] as $row){
            $thirdcountryy .= $row . ', ';
        }
        $thirdcountryy = substr($thirdcountryy, 0, -2);
        $query = "INSERT INTO like_table(third) VALUES('".$thirdcountryy."')";
        if(mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
            header("refresh:1 ; url=index.html");
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

After updating the Insert.php code. Data is being inserted as shown in the snapshot: [Data is being inserted like a 3x3 matrix. I want them to be inserted in a single row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2vz4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your insert.php having some errors.
Please use below code...

```html
<?php 
//insert.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "abcdef", "testing");

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $_POST = array_map(function($value) {
        return empty($value) ? "NULL" : $value;
    }, $_POST);
}
// var_dump($_POST);

if (isset($_POST)) {

    $markappcountry = !empty($_POST['markappcountry']) ? $_POST['markappcountry'] : "";
    $countryy = !empty($_POST['markcountry']) ? $_POST['markcountry'] : "";
    $thirdcountryy =     !empty($_POST['thirdcountry']) ? $_POST['thirdcountry'] : "";

    $framework = '';
    foreach($_POST["markappcountry"] as $row){
        $framework .= $row . ', ';
    }
    $framework = substr($framework, 0, -2);
    $countryy = '';
    foreach($_POST["markcountry"] as $row) {
        $countryy .= $row . ', ';
    }
    $countryy = substr($countryy, 0, -2);
    $thirdcountryy = '';
    foreach($_POST["thirdcountry"] as $row){
        $thirdcountryy .= $row . ', ';
    }
    $thirdcountryy = substr($thirdcountryy, 0, -2);
    $query = "INSERT INTO like_table(framework), like_table(country), like_table(third) VALUES('".$framework."','".$countryy."','".$thirdcountryy."')";
    if(mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
        header("refresh:1 ; url=index.html");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I used your code. Now, the selected values of third dropdown is also being inserted, but there's an issue. Values are being inserted in following way: Albania     NULL    NULL, NULL   Algeria   NULL, NULL     NULL     Yemen. That is, all the selected values are being individually inserted in each row. I want them to be in a single row. @Sarvan

Comment: you need to insert each value in each table ?

Comment: I want them to be inserted like:  Albania     Algeria     Yemen. not like a 3x3 matrix( Albania Null Null, Null Algeria Null, Null Null Yemen). @Sarvan

Comment: Please use and check the edited post... please let me know if it is worked or not...

Comment: Please tell me which format u need to store in db...
Example same table with three different types like first_country="Zaire", second_country="Algeria", third_country="Wallis"...
Or something else.
Storing the values in three different columns in same table...

Comment: I want them to be in three different columns in a same table and same row. I have updated the question.Please check

Comment: i updated the code and now nothing is being inserted in my db. It was working last time, but not now.

Comment: atleast upvote my question, else I'll be blocked from asking further questions. Thanks